# C# winform, how to set DataGridView VirtualMode in one or more DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, virtualmode

I'm working on a windows form project. In my form I have two DataGridViews.

I'd like to set two DataGridViews to DataGridView.VirtualMode.

Is there any efficient way to do this task except creating twice code like following?

Seeking your advice, Thanks in advance.

```
DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();
DataGridView dgv2 = new DataGridView();

ArrayList expense_summary_codes1 = new ArrayList();
Expense_Summary_Code expense_summary_codeInEdit1;
int rowInEdit1 = -1;
bool rowScopeCommit1 = false;

ArrayList expense_summary_codes2 = new ArrayList();
Expense_Summary_Code expense_summary_codeInEdit2;
int rowInEdit2 = -1;
bool rowScopeCommit2 = false;

... ellipsis

    private void dgv_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        switch(dgv.Name)
        {
             case "dgv1":                     
                 if (e.RowIndex == dgv.RowCount - 1) return;            

                 Expense_Summary_Code expense_summary_codeTmp1 = null;
                 if (e.RowIndex == rowInEdit1)
                 {
                     expense_summary_codeTmp1 = this.expense_summary_codeInEdit1;

                     ...
                 }
                 ...

                 break;
             case "dgv2":
                 if (e.RowIndex == dgv.RowCount - 1) return;            

                 Expense_Summary_Code expense_summary_codeTmp2 = null;
                 if (e.RowIndex == rowInEdit2)
                 {
                     expense_summary_codeTmp2 = this.expense_summary_codeInEdit2;

                     ...
                 }
                 ...

                 break;
        }
    }

    private void dgv_CellValuePushed(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`  in 2013 ?

Comment: Which version of  .Net framework your application running on?

Comment: @Toan Vo V3.5 sp1 of .Net framework running on.

Comment: @Habib no specific reason, just from DataGridView.VirtualMode of msdn library